# problem understanding a complicated reduce function

Tags: javascript

this function returns the oldest person and from what I understand the reduce function is about returning an accumulated value but I have been trying to understand this function for so long and I couldn't. where is the value to be accumulated

```
const people = [
  {
    name: "Carly",
    yearOfBirth: 2018,
  },
  {
    name: "Ray",
    yearOfBirth: 1962,
    yearOfDeath: 2011,
  },
  {
    name: "Jane",
    yearOfBirth: 1912,
    yearOfDeath: 1941,
  },
]



const findTheOldest = function(array) {
  return array.reduce((oldest, currentPerson) => {
    const oldestAge = getAge(oldest.yearOfBirth, oldest.yearOfDeath);
    const currentAge = getAge(currentPerson.yearOfBirth, currentPerson.yearOfDeath);
    return oldestAge < currentAge ? currentPerson : oldest;
  })
};

const getAge = function(birth, death) {
  if (!death) {
    death = new Date().getFullYear();
  }
  return death - birth;
};

module.exports = findTheOldest;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the accumulator here is the older person between the comparison of 2 people. What your code does is comparing 2 people, if one of them is the oldest, then it's compared to the next one, then you keep the oldest between them 2 and so on. At the end you just return the oldest. Instead of summing up things like you would normally do, you just return a value which is the older person so it's compared to the next one:

```
return oldestAge < currentAge ? currentPerson : oldest;
```

That line verifies which is the oldest between 2

```
if(current is older than previous)
   return currentPerson;
else
   return oldest; (which would be the previous value)
```

Comment: your explanation along with the simple analogy helped me understand the problem better! thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

The reduce function is commonly used to accumulate values, but that isn’t how it has to work.

You have a callback function which gets some arguments. The first two are:

- The value returned from the previous call to the callback function
- The current value from the array

When you run out of items in the array, the `reduce` function returns the return value of the last call to the callback function.

---

In this case it gets two arguments which are named `oldest` and `currentPerson`.

`oldest` is whatever is returned from the previous call to the function. So it is the “oldest person object that has been examined so far”.

`currentPerson` is the one currently being looked at on the array.

It compares the age of the two people and returns whichever of them is the oldest one.

In the end, you get the oldest value from the whole array.

Comment: your explanation made a difference i have been stuck for awhile i am so grateful to you